# Get information in my customized listview

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, xamarin

I have a customized `ListView` with checkboxes. I want get the values of the `TextView` with checked checkbox.

My example is not working:

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Text;

namespace Chamada 
{
    [Activity (Label = "Chamada", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {

    private SqlConnection con = null;
    private SqlCommand cmd = null;

    List<Chamada> chamada = new List<Chamada>();

    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);

        con = new SqlConnection ("");

        con.Open ();

        cmd = new SqlCommand ("", con);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter (cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet ();
        da.Fill (ds);

        foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows) {
            if (row ["Imagem"].ToString () == "1") {
              chamada.Add (new Chamada (row ["Ds_Nome"].ToString (), row ["Cd_Prefixo"].ToString (), Resource.Drawable.sucesso));
            } else {
                chamada.Add (new Chamada (row ["Ds_Nome"].ToString (), row ["Cd_Prefixo"].ToString (), Resource.Drawable.erro));
            }
        }

        ListView listView = FindViewById<ListView> (Resource.Id.lsv_Chamar);

        listView.Adapter = new adapter_list (this, chamada);


        Button button = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.btn_Save);

        button.Click += Gravar_Click; 

    }



    **// this is the part of code that is not working**
    **void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var builder = new StringBuilder();
        var sparseArray = FindViewById<ListView> (Resource.Id.lsv_Chamar);
        TextView text = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.txt_Prefixo);
        CheckBox check = FindViewById<CheckBox> (Resource.Id.checkBox1);
    for (var i = 0; i < sparseArray.Count; i++) 
        {
            //if (check.Checked) 
            //{
            //    builder.AppendLine (text.Text);
            //}

        }
        ShowAlert ("ListView", builder.ToString ()); 
    }**




    private void ShowAlert(string title, string message)
    {
        Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.Create();
        alertDialog.SetTitle(title);


        alertDialog.SetIcon(Android.Resource.Drawable.IcDialogAlert);
        alertDialog.SetMessage(message);
        alertDialog.SetButton("OK", (s, ev) =>
                              {
            //DO Something
        });
        alertDialog.Show();
    }

 }
}
```

This is my xml where the listview is attached:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:background="#ffffffff">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <TextView
        android:text="Prefixo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:typeface="normal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/txt_Prefixo"
        android:layout_marginRight="5.0dp" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="640.0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Nome"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:typeface="normal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/txt_Nome"
        android:layout_marginRight="5.0dp" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/erro"
        android:layout_width="38.0dp"
        android:layout_height="39.0dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="17.0dp" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:shadowColor="#ff110707" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Main.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#ffffffff"
android:minWidth="25px"
android:minHeight="25px">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/degrade_fundo">
    <TextView
        android:text="Lista de Chamada"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:textSize="13dp"
        android:id="@+id/txt_Titulo"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="#ff949494">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="31dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <TextView
            android:text="Prefixo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#ffe0e0e0"
            android:typeface="normal"
            android:id="@+id/cabe_Prefixo"
            android:layout_marginRight="5.0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="640.0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Nome"
            android:textColor="#ffe0e0e0"
            android:typeface="normal"
            android:id="@+id/cabe_Nome"
            android:layout_marginRight="5.0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Status"
            android:textColor="#ffe0e0e0"
            android:typeface="normal"
            android:id="@+id/cabe_Status"
            android:layout_marginRight="5.0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:typeface="normal"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/cabe_Check"
            android:layout_marginRight="5.0dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<ListView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/lsv_Chamar"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
<Button
    android:text="@string/Save"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_width="177.0dp"
    android:layout_height="36.0dp"
    android:id="@+id/btn_Gravar"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginRight="0.0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="382.0dp"
    android:fadingEdge="none"
    android:background="@drawable/botao_style" />
```

Comment: What's not working, where's it failing?

Comment: What is `Save_Click` attached to?

Comment: my Loop not runs my values.

Comment: Have you tried `sparseArray.CheckedItemIDs()`? http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=P:Android.Widget.ListView.CheckedItemPositions?

Comment: In the `Save_Click` perhaps?

Comment: Yes, the problem happens when I click in the button, and the loop don't runs the all listview, only shows the first row.